# ImportMany not working with Custom Metadata Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I have created a custom Metadata Attribute for ImportMany in MEF, but ImportMany is always null.

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class ,AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ModuleAttribute : ExportAttribute ,IModuleMetadata
{
    public ModuleAttribute(string contract)
        : base(typeof(IScreen))
    {
        Name = contract;
        Region = Region.Sidebar;
        IsVisible = true;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public short Order { get; set; }
    public Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I export my class.

```
[Module("Stock" ,Module = "Stock" ,Order = 1 ,Permissions = Permissions.View)]
    internal sealed class StockWorkSpaceViewModel : Screen
```

where Screen is `typeof(IScreen)`

Here is my ImportMany.

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen ,IModuleMetadata>> Modules { get; set; }
```

Can anyone predict, where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you also add the declaration of IModuleMetadata? Does it have matching read-only properties?

Comment: Yesterday, I was able to import, when I removed the default constructor from the class. If the class has parameterless constructor with some code. Import is not work. Also I have to remove the contract name from Export, i.e., I had to export with contract type.

Comment: I also had an other Custom Export called Settings, but now ImportMany for settings includes types from ModuleExport. I dont know why. Both has different metadata interface but same contract type.

Comment: There's so much that can go wrong here. If you don't more code, it will be hard to guess. You could try adding a complete example that fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check up the ComponnetContainer.ComposeParts
2. Check up the export and import attribute which must be the same
3. Check up the Customs Attribute and the interface you used in the lazy initialization. The property must be the same.That means the customs attribute class implement the lazy initialization implicit.